# Generate random hexadecimal colour in Twig

Tags: symfony, colors, twig, hex

I want to generate random hex colors in Twig, to use it for example as a background in something like this:

```
{% for organization in organizations %}
    {
        value: {{ organization.value }},
        color: "#F56954",
        label: "{{ organization.name }}"
    },
{% endfor %}
```

Any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to randomise a know set of data (in order to exclude no sense values) as follow:

```
{% for organization in organizations %}
    {
        value: {{ organization.value }},
        color: "{{ random(['#H54924', '#F36252', '#F56954']) }}"
        label: "{{ organization.name }}"
    },
{% endfor %}
```

EDIT:

For pure random values, you can try the following approach:

```
{% set values = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']%}
{% for organization in organizations %}
    {
        value: {{ organization.value }},
        color: "#{{random(values)~ random(values)~ random(values)~ random(values)~ random(values)~ random(values)  }}",
        label: "{{ organization.name }}"
    },
{% endfor %}
{{ '#' ~ random(values) ~ random(values) ~ random(values) ~ random(values) ~ random(values) ~ random(values)  }}
```

[Here](https://twigfiddle.com/5phaec) a working example

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

```
class SomeUtil
{
    /**
     * @return string hex color string (RGB): #XXXXXX
     */
    public static function randHexColor()
    {
        return sprintf("#%06s", dechex(rand(0, 256**3-1)));
    }

    /**
     * @param int $rangeFrom [0..255]
     * @param int $rangeTo [0..255]
     * @return string hex color string (RGB): #XXXXXX
     */
    public static function rangedRandHexColor($rangeFrom = null, $rangeTo = null)
    {
        $min = 0;
        $max = 255;
        if ($rangeFrom === null || !NumberUtil::inRange($rangeFrom, $min, $max)) {
            $rangeFrom = $min;
        }
        if ($rangeTo === null || !NumberUtil::inRange($rangeTo, $min, $max)) {
            $rangeTo = $max;
        }
        if ($rangeFrom === $min && $rangeTo === $max) {
            return self::randHexColor();
        } else {
            return sprintf("#%02s", dechex(rand($rangeFrom, $rangeTo)))
                .sprintf("%02s", dechex(rand($rangeFrom, $rangeTo)))
                .sprintf("%02s", dechex(rand($rangeFrom, $rangeTo)));
        }
    }

}
```

In controller

```
$data['util'] = new SomeUtil();

return $this->renderView('AppBundle:Foo:bar.html.twig', $data);
```

In twig

```
{{ util.randHexColor() }}
```

or

```
{{ util.rangedRandHexColor(180, 220) }}
```

to exclude dark and LSD colors